# proof that all subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ are of the form $H = b\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, integers

In the proof that every subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ is of the type $H=b\mathbb{Z}$ for some integer $b$, Artin (in his book Algebra) argues that if $b\in H$, [b is the smallest positive integer in $H$] then $kb\in H$. The proof by induction is quite straightforward. It is true for $k=1$, then assume it to be true for $k=r$ and then show for $k=r+1$.

However, induction does not give me much insight and I am unable to see if $b\in H$, then how $2b\in H$. (Is it because if $b\in H$, then $b+b\in H$, the product operation applied to same element?). But in groups you do the product with other elements of the group, not the same element.

Comment: Can you show me two elements $p$ and $q$ in $H$ such that $p+q=nb$ or just take the simple case $n=2$ (given $b\in H$)

Comment: $x + y$ is defined in a group for any $x$ and $y$. That includes all cases when $x = y$. (It would be a bit of a disaster if you couldn't add 2 and 2 to get 4.)

Comment: The last sentence of your question, "But in groups you do the product with other elements of the group, not the same element," is wrong.  A group is closed under the operation applied to *any* two of its elements, whether distinct or equal.

Comment: In the definition of $H$ being a subgroup, one requires that, for $a,b\in H$, then $ab\in H$. There's no implicit requirement that $a\ne b$, and they certainly can be equal.

Comment: Thank you, I wonder how I failed to realize this.

Answer (score 1):

Let $H$ be any non trivial and proper subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}$ and let $a\in H$ be smallest positive integer ,then it is clear that $a\Bbb{Z} \subset H$. If $b\in H$ st $b\neq an$ for any $n \in \Bbb{Z}$ then by Division Algorithm $\exists q ,r $ st $b=aq+r$ where $0<r<a$ , but this implies that $r=b-aq\in a\Bbb{Z}$ contadiction to our assumption that $a$ is smallest. Thus every element of $H$ is of the type $an$ i.e $H=a\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: sorry but how does this does not answer my question? I have asked: given $b$ is smallest positive integer in $H$, show me how $2b$ can be an element of $H$

Comment: I'm giving an independent proof